# How do I check if an element occurs more than twice in an array, subject to a string pattern?

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I know how to check if an eleemnt has never occurred more than twice in an array, using

```
data_arr.count(string) <= 2
```

but what if my array is

```
["1/5", "2/6", "3/5", "4/7", "3/8", "3/9"]
```

how do I check that the first number before the "/" never occurs more than twice when it is found before the "/"?  That is, in the above example, "1" never occurs more than twice (only in the element "1/5") but "3" occurrs 3 times before the "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might begin by using [hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a default value of zero to construct a *counting hash*.

```
arr = ["1/5", "2/6", "3/5", "4/7", "3/8", "3/9"]

h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s[/\d+(?=\/)/]] += 1 }
  #> {"1"=>1, "2"=>1, "3"=>3, "4"=>1}
```

Then write

```
h.any? { |_,v| v > 2 }
  #=>  true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
2.2.1 :005 > array = ["1/5", "2/6", "3/5", "4/7", "3/8", "3/9"]
 => ["1/5", "2/6", "3/5", "4/7", "3/8", "3/9"] 
2.2.1 :006 > array.count{|m| m.match(/3\//) }
 => 3
```

This works by "passing a block" to the **count** method.  The block is evaluated for each item **m** and if true, the item is 'counted.'

In this case I'm using a regular expression to select items with '3' before the slash.

re: comments, you can interpolate any number you'd like into the regex/string/whatever as follows:

```
regex: /#{variable}/
string: "#{string}"
```

Comment: Or just use `m.start_with?("3/")`

Comment: Why would you hardcode `3/`??? If you only tailor it to the example given in the question, you might as well just return `true` directly.

Comment: I was providing an example of how one might evaluate "m" against a statement to obtain a 'true' or 'false' from the block passed to 'count'.  This does presume someone reading knows how to interpolate a variable into a regular expression (or in akuhn's case a string).  I'll amend the answer to include instructions for this, but it's not directly related to the question being asked, which is why I did not think to include it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step I would suggest is to do a string-split on each string of your array. That way, you could check for recurrences among the integers.

For example, for each element in your array, do 
`array[element].split("")` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if ANY numerator* has occurred more than twice in the array you use this code:

```
data_arr.each do |element|
  numerator = element.match(/(.+)\//)
  if data_arr.count {|e| e.match(/^#{numerator}\//)} > 2
    # do something if the element matches more than twice
  end
end
```

* [numerator](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/numerator) is the number before the / in division.